# Почему виснет консоль в QT CREATOR на std::cin?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, gcc, cmake

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
    std::cout << k + 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На [cpp.sh](https://cpp.sh/74xvs) работает, но в qt creator почему то нет. Бесконечно зависает на cin, можно сколько угодно вводить числа, к `std::cout` так и не переходит. CMakeLists стандартный:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Stepic)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

Debian 9, QT Creator 4.2.0 (Based on Qt 5.7.1)

Comment: @Witalik Конечно можно и обойтись, только к решению проблемы это отношение не имеет.

Comment: @Witalik - зачем вы даете плохие советы? `using namespace std;` это плохое предложение. Замена k+1 на ++k также (теперь переменная поменяла значение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у QtCreator есть Application Output, который предназначен только для вывода, не для ввода информации! 
Однако, всегда можно поставить галку для "Run in terminal" 
(Projects->Run Settings->Run in terminal)